# How to get 'edit mode' page in full browser instead of PopUp in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have created Blog Site as default site in SharePoint 2010. When i go to individual blog post it shows default "edit" link at Right side with which you can edit the posted blog content. I need browser to open in full page instead of pop up after clicking this "edit"  button.How do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/908def07-c28d-4ca6-b675-81f06fe48265) address same question . Check the Ashar2k11 answer. Basically you have to customize XSLT in XSLListViewWebPArt in the Post.aspx page

Answer (score 0):

Open ur Blog site in sharepoint designer on that u can edit.

master page: v4.master
content page: home.aspx/default.aspx pages open this pages.what u want can edit

after editing pages once save the sharepoint designer then goto ur sharepoint site refresh site displaying that site is edited.

Comment: where do i have to look in there'

Comment: Any item in list when edted , opens in popup .I need to get it in full page browser